# How to access and make use of html data in django?

Tags: html, django

I am having a hard time figuring out the right logic for my problem, i have 3 models,

```
class Item(SmartModel):

    name= models.CharField(max_length=64,help_text="Name for this item e.g Hamburger")

    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    optionalitems = models.ManyToManyField('optionalitems.OptionalItemCategory',null=True,blank=True)

class OptionalItems(SmartModel):
     """Optional items that belong to an item e.g topping that belongs to a pizza"""

     name = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Item name.")
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True,blank=True)

class OptionalItemCategory(SmartModel):
    """Category to which optional items belong"""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=20,help_text="Category name")
    optional_items = models.ManyToManyField(OptionalItems)
```

in my template,

```
{%for optionalcategory in optionalcategories %}
  <h5 id="blah"> {{ optionalcategory.title}} </h5>
  {% for optionalitem in optionalcategory.optional_items.all %}
   <ul>
    <input type="radio" value="radio" name="optional" value="op"><li id="item_appearence">{{optionalitem.name}}<span> {{optionalitem.price}}</span></li><a/>
   </ul>
  {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

So for example an `Item` like a burrito will have an `OptionalItem` steak or chicken.I am able to access the `Item` like so `item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=obj.id)` but my problem is i cannot figure out how to capture the `OptionalItem`. I want to be able to access the `OptionalItem`, i want to obtain the value of the radio button and its attributes. its kind of tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is inconsistent and that makes it hard to read, understand and work with. Some advice, clean it up. Something like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Option(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option)
```

Than you need a from and a view. As I interpret your question: you want a form to select a option for an Item. So the code below will render all options and the widget RadioSelect() lets the user select one item. But why use radiobuttons? If an Item has a relation to one Option, than the Item model should have a foreignKey not M2M!

Form:

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    options = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ( 'options', )
```

View:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

```
def your_view(request, id):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=id) # Your item object.
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            options = form.cleaned_data['options']
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ArticleForm(instance=article)

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Template:

```
{% for obj in item.options_set.all %}
    {{ obj.name }} {{ obj.price }}
{% endfor %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I dind't test the code. But this should get you started. The documentation is your friend:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/#forms

Comment: grateful for the advice but your answer kinda pushes me into a different direction..what am tryin to achieve is be able to access the selected optional_item(radio button) and make queries on it like with item = get_object_or_404(Item,pk=obj.id)

Comment: I don't understand what you try to accomplish and I don't want you in a different direction. But your coding style makes things "kind of tricky" to understand and work with. So I started by cleaning things up. Please supply your form and view code.

Comment: i get your point, my coding has a long way to go but thats why am asking here and speaking of forms , i didn't define a form. please inform me on how i could go about it with a form.

Comment: Start with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/ and then for more details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/#forms

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you can simply render the price. I'd write a method in the `Item` model, that formats the `OptionalItems` the way you like.

i.e.

```
class Item(SmartModel)
    ...
    def get_optional(self):
        return ','.join([a.optionalitems for a in self.optionalitems.all()])
```

Of course, you should change that method to have it format the way you'd like.

If you pass a queryset of `Items` to your template, you can do something like the following:

```
{% for item in items %}
    Name: {{ item.name}}
    Price: {{ item.price }}
    Optional Items: {{ item.get_optional }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i can render the price fine but i want to be able to obtain the optional item object after submission so that i can make queries on it. sorry if my question is misleading,must be ma poor english

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that `OptionalItems` also has a price. You can customize how it renders by changing the `get_optional` method, to display it the way you like. You can just address the attributes in the `OptionalItems` class.

Comment: sorry man, i don't get the comment above,newbie but am going to give it a shot.